# How to expend a super class object to a sub class in php?

Tags: php, inheritance, singleton

i want to implement singleton in the data base super class.
but i want to invoke the methods from it on a sub class object

super class:

```
class Database {

    private $conn;

    public static $instance;

    private function __construct($conn)
    {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    public static function getInstance($conn)
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new Database($conn);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

sub class:

class Article extends Database
{
public function __construct($conn)
{

        parent::getInstance($conn);
}
}
```

--->

```
$article = new Article($conn);
```

but $conn property is not getting initialised.
is there any successful way of doing that without calling directly the super class constructor and keeping the superclass singleton design pattern? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Singleton, you instantiate the class by calling its static method *getInstance()* and send parameters to stablish connection to the database, make the connection and assing it to non-static variable `$conn`:

```
class Database {

    // Private to ensure you can get instance only by the static method
    private static $instance;
    
    // $conn is not static
    private $conn;

    private function __construct()
    {
        // Declared to avoid non-static instatiation
    }

    public static function getInstance($host, $user, $pass)
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {
            self::$instance = new self();
            // Connect to database
            self::$instance->$con = new PDO($host, $user, $pass);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

__construct() and getInstance() are already defined in parent class, no need to overwrite them

```
class Article extends Database
{
    public function prepare($query)
    {
        return $this->conn->prepare($query);
    }
}
```

Instantiate the model and start doing something:

```
$article = Article::getInstance("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=UTF8", 'myuser', 'mypass');
$stmt = $article->prepare('SELECT * FROM sometable');
```